# Live Charts set separator to edges

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

Using Live Charts with a WPF application.

Currently the separator is set to the label I want the separator to be set to the edges/border of the label

Mock up of current graph

```
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |
A   B   C   D
```

How I would like the graph to look

```
|   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |
  A   B   C   D
```

Edit: Wanted to mention that the Live Chart [Basic Column](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wf/Basic%20Column) has the look I want (notice the lines on the x-axis of the graph), but mine keeps coming out like the [Basic Line](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wf/Basic%20Line%20Chart)

Comment: This is not supported in the current version of the library, BasicColumn works like you do because of the type fo the series, in a column series the point has an area, and the label is centered in this area, in a line series we don't have this.

Comment: I have a mix of two types of graphs, the column and a line.  So I have a do have a column series.  Is there a way to specify which one to use when drawing the lines?

Answer (score 0):

I used axis sections to work around this

```
    myChart.AxisX(0).Sections = New LiveCharts.Wpf.SectionsCollection
    myChart.AxisX(0).Sections.Add(New LiveCharts.Wpf.AxisSection With {.FromValue = -0.5,
                                 .ToValue = -0.5, .Stroke = Brushes.Gainsboro, .StrokeThickness = 0.5})

    For Each xSec In x.Labels.Select(Function(fn) New LiveCharts.Wpf.AxisSection With {.FromValue = x.Labels.IndexOf(fn) + 0.5,
                                 .ToValue = x.Labels.IndexOf(fn) + 0.5, .Stroke = Brushes.Gainsboro, .StrokeThickness = 0.5})
        myChart.AxisX(0).Sections.Add(xSec)
    Next
```

Note: obviously this only works if your labels are unique otherwise you'll need to implement a different loop